# Changing Status from published to Draft wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to edit the content of a published page in wordpress. Can I do this, by changing its page status from published to draft? Is it possible or are there any plugins that can be used?

(Wordpress 4.1.1)

Comment: changing status of post will make your post/page absent from frontend. You don't need to change status for only update the content.

Comment: Whenever i try to edit the page i cannot see any content either in the visuals nor in the text and how to bring back the content to the editor inorder to modification